# android andengine hanoi tower how to add ring

Tags: android, andengine, towers-of-hanoi

I am using android SDK, Eclipse and AndEngine
I have created hanoi tower game which works perfectly with 3 rings.
When I added one more ring the program malfunctions. 
How can I fix that? Is that caused from the dimension of my 4th ring
or is something in the code to be set?
Here is my code with the 4 rings, which crashes at collisions between 2,4 rings or 1,3 rings and so on.

```
    @Override
     protected void onCreateResources() {
     try {

        main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(),   this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 40, true, Color.BLUE);
         main_font.load();
        // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
        backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new    IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring4 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring4.png");
            }
        });
        mButtonTextureRegion = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/button.png");
            }
        });

        // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM
        backgroundTexture.load();
        towerTexture.load();
        ring1.load();
        ring2.load();
        ring3.load();
        ring4.load();
        mButtonTextureRegion.load();


    //    try {
    //      this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 2, 1));
    //      this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
        //} catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        //  Debug.e(e);
        //}

        this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
        this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
        this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
        this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
        this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);
        this.mRing4 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring4);
        this.mbutton = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(mButtonTextureRegion);

        // 4 - Create the stacks
        this.mStack1 = new Stack<Ring>();
        this.mStack2 = new Stack<Ring>();
        this.mStack3 = new Stack<Ring>();
        // mButtonTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas,this,"rectangle_one.png", 2,1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);
    // 2 - Add the towers
    mTower1 = new Sprite(195, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower2 = new Sprite(450, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower3 = new Sprite(654, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    //mbutton = (ITextureRegion) new Sprite(604, 463, (ITextureRegion) this.mButtonTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    scene.attachChild(mTower1);
    scene.attachChild(mTower2);
    scene.attachChild(mTower3);

    // 3 - Create the rings
    Ring ring1 = new Ring(1, 155, 122, this.mRing1, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, 
                pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    Ring ring2 = new Ring(2, 134, 162, this.mRing2, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, 
                pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    Ring ring3 = new Ring(3, 113, 205, this.mRing3, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, 
                pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    Ring ring4 = new Ring(4, 90, 250, this.mRing4, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, 
                pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    intent= new Intent(this, MainActivity4.class);
    ButtonSprite mButtonSprite = new ButtonSprite(670,0, mbutton,
               mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager())
    {

         @Override
         public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                 float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY){
             scene.detachChild(gameOverText);
             moves=0;
             //scene.reset();
            //scene=onCreateScene();
            //mEngine.setScene(scene);

             startActivity(intent);

             return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }

     };  


    scene.attachChild(ring1);
    scene.attachChild(ring2);
    scene.attachChild(ring3);
    scene.attachChild(ring4);
    //button.setPosition(0, 200);
    scene.attachChild(mButtonSprite);

    // 4 - Add all rings to stack one
    this.mStack1.add(ring4);
    this.mStack1.add(ring3);
    this.mStack1.add(ring2);
    this.mStack1.add(ring1);
    // 5 - Initialize starting position for each ring
    ring1.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring2.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring3.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring4.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring1.setmTower(mTower1);
    ring2.setmTower(mTower1);
    ring3.setmTower(mTower1);
    ring4.setmTower(mTower1);
    // 6 - Add touch handlers
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring1);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring2);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring3);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring4);

    scene.registerTouchArea(mButtonSprite);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

    countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:"+moves ,10, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    countText.setText("Κινήσεις:"+String.valueOf(moves));
    countText.setPosition(0,0);
    scene.attachChild(countText);
    minMoves = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Κερδίζεις με 15" ,20, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());       

    //start = new Button(0, 0, main_font, "Min moves:"+7 ,10, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());     
    minMoves.setPosition(260,0);
    scene.attachChild(minMoves);



    return scene;
}
private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
    Stack<Ring> stack = null;
    Sprite tower = null;
    if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 ||             
            ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack1;
        tower = mTower1;
        moves++;
    } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || 
            ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack2.peek()).getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack2;
        tower = mTower2;
        moves++;
    } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || 
            ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack3.peek()).getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack3;
        tower = mTower3;
        moves++;

    } else {
        stack = ring.getmStack();
        tower = ring.getmTower();
    }
    ring.getmStack().remove(ring);


    if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - 
            ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - 
            ring.getHeight());

    } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - 
            ring.getWidth()/2, (stack.peek()).getY() - 
            ring.getHeight());

    }
    stack.add(ring);
    ring.setmStack(stack);
    ring.setmTower(tower);

    if(countText != null){
        countText.setText("Κινήσεις:"+ moves);
  }
    scene.detachChild(gameOverText);
    //check if game is over
    if (isGameOver())
    {

        moves=0;

    }

}

private Boolean isGameOver() {
        String gameover;
        if(mStack3.size() == 4 ||mStack2.size() == 4  ){

            if (moves>15)
            {   
                gameover="Εχασες "+moves+" κινήσεις";

            }
            else 
            {
                gameover="Κέρδισες!";

            }
            Font main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.GREEN);
            main_font.load();
                gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, gameover, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager())
             {

                 @Override
                 public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                         float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY){


                     //scene.clearTouchAreas();
                     return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
                }
             };  
             gameOverText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - gameOverText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2*gameOverText.getHeight());          

             scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

             //scene.clearTouchAreas();
return true;
        }
        return false;
       }
```

But this code works perfectly for 3 rings.

```
@Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, 
        new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        try {


            //this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 512, 512);

            //mButtonTextureRegion = (ITexture) BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "button.png");
            //mButtonTextureRegion = (ITexture) BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas,this,"button.png", 2,1); 

            main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 40, true, Color.WHITE);
             main_font.load();
            // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
            backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
                }
            });
           // ITexture ring4 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
              //  @Override
               // public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                 //   return getAssets().open("gfx/ring4.png");
               // }
           // });
            mButtonTextureRegion = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/button.png");
                }
            });
            mButtonQuitTextureRegion = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/exit_button.png");
                }
            });


            // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM
            backgroundTexture.load();
            towerTexture.load();
            ring1.load();
            ring2.load();
            ring3.load();
            //ring4.load();
            mButtonTextureRegion.load();
            mButtonQuitTextureRegion.load();


            this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
            this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
            this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
            this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
            this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);
            //this.mRing4 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring4);
            this.mbutton = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(mButtonTextureRegion);
            this.mbuttonQuit = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(mButtonQuitTextureRegion);

            // 4 - Create the stacks
            this.mStack1 = new Stack();
            this.mStack2 = new Stack();
            this.mStack3 = new Stack();
            // mButtonTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas,this,"rectangle_one.png", 2,1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {

        Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);
        // 2 - Add the towers
        mTower1 = new Sprite(195, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mTower2 = new Sprite(400, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mTower3 = new Sprite(604, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        //mbutton = (ITextureRegion) new Sprite(604, 463, (ITextureRegion) this.mButtonTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        scene.attachChild(mTower1);
        scene.attachChild(mTower2);
        scene.attachChild(mTower3);

        // 3 - Create the rings
                Ring ring1 = new Ring(1, 139, 174, this.mRing1, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                            return false;
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, 
                            pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                Ring ring2 = new Ring(2, 118, 212, this.mRing2, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                            return false;
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, 
                            pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                Ring ring3 = new Ring(3, 97, 255, this.mRing3, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                            return false;
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, 
                            pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };

        intent= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        menu_intent= new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        ButtonSprite mButtonSprite = new ButtonSprite(670,0, mbutton,
                   mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager())
        {

             @Override
             public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                     float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY){
                 scene.detachChild(gameOverText);
                 moves=0;
                 //scene.reset();
                //scene=onCreateScene();
                //mEngine.setScene(scene);

                 startActivity(intent);

                 return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
            }

         };  
         ButtonSprite mButtonQuitSprite = new ButtonSprite(670,330, mbuttonQuit,
                   mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager())
        {

             @Override
             public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                     float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY){
                 //moveTaskToBack(true);
                 startActivity(menu_intent);

                 return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
            }

         }; 


        scene.attachChild(ring1);
        scene.attachChild(ring2);
        scene.attachChild(ring3);
        //scene.attachChild(ring4);
        //button.setPosition(0, 200);
        scene.attachChild(mButtonSprite);
        scene.attachChild(mButtonQuitSprite);

        // 4 - Add all rings to stack one
        //this.mStack1.add(ring4);
        this.mStack1.add(ring3);
        this.mStack1.add(ring2);
        this.mStack1.add(ring1);
        // 5 - Initialize starting position for each ring
        ring1.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring2.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring3.setmStack(mStack1);
        //ring4.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring1.setmTower(mTower1);
        ring2.setmTower(mTower1);
        ring3.setmTower(mTower1);
        //ring4.setmTower(mTower1);
        // 6 - Add touch handlers
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring1);
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring2);
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring3);
        //scene.registerTouchArea(ring4);

        scene.registerTouchArea(mButtonSprite);
        scene.registerTouchArea(mButtonQuitSprite);
        scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

        countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:"+moves ,10, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        countText.setText("Κινήσεις:"+String.valueOf(moves));
        countText.setPosition(0,0);
        scene.attachChild(countText);
        minMoves = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Κερδίζεις με 7" ,20, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());        

        //start = new Button(0, 0, main_font, "Min moves:"+7 ,10, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());     
        minMoves.setPosition(260,0);
        scene.attachChild(minMoves);
        return scene;
    }
    private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
        Stack stack = null;
        Sprite tower = null;
        if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 ||             
                ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
            stack = mStack1;
            tower = mTower1;
            moves++;
        } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || 
                ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack2.peek()).getmWeight())) {
            stack = mStack2;
            tower = mTower2;
            moves++;
        } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || 
                ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack3.peek()).getmWeight())) {
            stack = mStack3;
            tower = mTower3;
            moves++;

        } else {
            stack = ring.getmStack();
            tower = ring.getmTower();
        }
        ring.getmStack().remove(ring);


        if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
            ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - 
                ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - 
                ring.getHeight());

        } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
            ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - 
                ring.getWidth()/2, ((Ring) stack.peek()).getY() - 
                ring.getHeight());

        }
        stack.add(ring);
        ring.setmStack(stack);
        ring.setmTower(tower);



        //gameToast(String.valueOf(moves));
        if(countText != null){
            countText.setText("Κινήσεις:"+ moves);
      }
        scene.detachChild(gameOverText);
        //check if game is over
        if (isGameOver())
        {
            //toastText("Game over",34, toastLayout,getApplicationContext());
            String msg="Game is over with"+String.valueOf(moves)+" moves";
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //gameToast(msg);
            moves=0;

        }

    }
    private void resetVars()
    {       
        scene = new Scene();
    }

    private Boolean isGameOver() {
        String gameover;
        if(mStack3.size() == 3 ||mStack2.size() == 3  ){

            if (moves>7)
            {   
                gameover="Εχασες "+moves+" κινήσεις";

            }
            else 
            {
                gameover="Κέρδισες!";

            }
            Font main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.RED);
            main_font.load();
                gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, gameover, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager())
             {

                 @Override
                 public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                         float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY){


                     //scene.clearTouchAreas();
                     return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
                }
             };  
             gameOverText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - gameOverText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2*gameOverText.getHeight());          

             scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

             //scene.clearTouchAreas();
return true;
        }
        return false;
       }
```

What is the difference?

Comment: post your log so we can see what error exactly you have there

Comment: I don't have a log, I run through phone...I don't use emulator...I don't have an error. There is a phone crashing. Thanks.

Comment: if you use Eclipse and try to run your code for testing or debugging you should have a tab called LogCat. See here: http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/11/android-tutorial-7-how-to-debug-the-android-mobile-application-with-logcat/ Try to use it. there you can see where exactly you have an error, even if you test your code on your device (as long as it is connected via USB)